# Java - Typecasting from Java.lang.Object to an instance of a custom Class

Tags: java, stack

Is there a way to typecast from Java.lang.Object to an instance of a custom defined class.

Essentially, I have created a Stack (java.util.Stack) and have pushed into it instances of type my_class. But when I pop out from the Stack, I receive an instance of type Java.lang.Object.

Do I have to create a constructor in my_class that can create my_class instances from Java.lang.Object ?

---

**Generics** is the best way to go. I am pretty new to Java, and without realizing about generics (same as in C++ STL), I have been doing a lot of typecasting like-

to convert to an integer: new Integer((Java.lang.Object).toString()).intValue()

Guess those days are gone now :) Thanks for making my life easy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should write code using generics.  For example instead of

```
MyObject someObj = ...;
Stack myStack = new Stack();
myStack.push(someObj);
someObj = myStack.pop(); // Error!
```

you can let the stack know about the type of object within:

```
MyObject someObj = ...;
Stack<MyObject> myStack = new Stack<MyObject>();
myStack.push(someObj);
someObj = myStack.pop(); // Now this works!
```

If for whatever reason this isn't feasible, you can cast:

```
MyObject someObj = ...;
Stack myStack = new Stack();
myStack.push(someObj);
someObj = (MyObject) myStack.pop(); // This works too, but is considered very bad style
```

Answer (score 6):

You can cast the object like this:

```
my_class myObj = (my_class)obj;
```

But if you define your stack as a stack of `my_class` then you don't need to bother with casting:

```
Stack<my_class> myStack = new Stack<my_class>();
```

Answer (score 1):

No, you need to read up on [Java Generics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/index.html)

```
java.util.Stack<myObject> myStack = new java.util.Stack<myObject>();
```

Comment: I agree about generics, but the answer to the question is not no.

Comment: If you're writing new code, then yes, it is. There's literally no reason to cast to and from `Object` and it is considered a bad practice with modern Java. (And besides, that wasn't actually his question - the only question mark I see is after something that the answer is definitely "no" :) )

Answer (score 0):

Is this a serious question?

My_class myClassObj = (My_class) obj;

Actually as in any other language I know.
Or do I get your question wrong?

**Edit**

You could of course also use a generic Stack.
Just read the title of your question actually ;)

Answer (score 0):

In reference to the accepted response:

"`MyObject someObj = ...;
Stack myStack = new Stack();
myStack.push(someObj);
someObj = (MyObject) myStack.pop();`"

As noted, yes, `someObj = (MyObject) myStack.pop();` isn't the safest.  However, if you're still looking to cast an object, use `instanceof`

EX:

`Object obj = myStack.pop();
 MyObject someObj = null;
 if( obj instanceof MyObject )
     someObj = (MyObject) obj;`

Answer (score -1):

```
qlist=dao.getdistinctquestion();
            System.out.println(qlist);
            List<QuestionMaster> alist = new ArrayList<QuestionMaster>();
            int i=1, c=0;  String sub="";
            for( QuestionMaster qq:qlist){
                System.out.println("element:"+qq.getSubject());
                if(i==1){
                    c=1;   // sub = qq.getSubject();
                }
                else
                if (qq.getSubject().equals(sub)==false){
                    QuestionMaster ss = new QuestionMaster();
                    ss.setSubject(sub);
                    ss.setTag(""+c);
                    alist.add(ss);
                    c=1;
                }
                else
                    c++;
                sub=qq.getSubject();
                i++;
            }
            QuestionMaster ss = new QuestionMaster();
                ss.setSubject(sub);
                ss.setTag(""+c);
                alist.add(ss);


            qlist=alist;
```

======================================================================

```
for(Object im:list){
            Object[] a=(Object[]) im;
            System.out.println("subject ="+a[0]+"total questions ="+a[1]);

        }
```

Comment: for(Object im:list){
      Object[] a=(Object[]) im;
      System.out.println("subject ="+a[0]+"total questions ="+a[1]);
      
     }

Comment: How is this answer helping anyone?